# Which of the first-order formulae are true in S?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

$S=(U, [.]), S=\{0,1,2\}, [P]=\{0,1\}, [R]=\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,2)\}$

a) $(\exists x~\exists y.R(x,y))\implies (\forall x.P(x))$

b) $\exists x~\exists y.(R(x,y) \implies \forall x.P(x))$

I think a) is false, because $P(x)$ can be true or false, so the right side of implication has to be false for the entire statement is true, and this is possible by setting $x=2$ and $y=2$.

I think b) is also true because similarly, we can select $R(x,y) = (2,2)$ so false implies anything is false.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: false implies anything is ...

Comment: In 2), you have $\exists x$, and then while that is going on, you have $\forall x$. Which $x$ is used in $P$? You can't say "There exists an $x$ such that for all $x$..."

Comment: @Arthur 2) is a perfectly good logic statement: the $x$ in $P(x)$ is a free variable within the scope of $\forall x$, and hence is quantified by the $\forall x$. But that means that the subformula $\forall x P(x)$ does not contain any free variable $x$, and thus the only free variable $x$ within the scope of the $\exists x$ (and thus the only $x$ that is quantified by the $\exists x$), is the $x$ in $R(x,y)$.

Comment: @Bram28 Like with global and local variables in programming, I would feel more comfortable if they had a different name. Even though it might technically be correct as it stands, I would say it is wrong because it invites an ambiguity which costs practically nothing to alleviate. The entire point of writing something down is to communicate it to someone else, and if you introduce a source for confusion and your sole defense is that technically it should be well-formulated to someone experienced in reading, then you've made a mistake in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you are quite right about that: using a different variable would certainly make it easier to read and use!  I guess I should have said that 2) is a 'perfectly syntactical correct' statement of logic ... but there are indeed 'better' ways to express what it is expressing. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Bram28 That being said, I realise that whoever wrote this problem probably wanted the two statements to be as typographically similar as he could make them. Still, he could've used $\forall z.P(z)$ in both formulas, and I would've been happier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is okay.   It demonstrates the importance of quantifier scope.

The conditional, $\exists x\exists y~R(x,y)~\to~\forall x~P(x)$, is false because the antecedant, $\exists x\exists y~R(x,y)$, is true while the consequent, $\forall x~P(x)$, is false.

The existential $\exists x~\exists y~\big(R(x,y)\to\forall x~ P(x)\big)$, is true because *the bound* conditional, $R(x,y)\to\forall x~ P(x)$ is true for any pair where $R(x,y)$ is false, and there does exist such a pair.